# Data not displaying in text field

Tags: post-meta, sanitization

I have been working on trying to get data to store and display on a CPT field. The code I have is here:

```
function fhaac_subject_box_callback( $post ){
     wp_nonce_field( basename(__FILE__ ), 'fhacc_subject_nounce');
     $fhaac_stored_subject_meta = get_post_meta( '$post->ID' );
?>

<div>Subject name: <input type="text" name="fhaac_subject_name" id="fhaac_
subject_name" value="<?php if ( ! empty ( $fhaac_stored_subject_meta 
['fhaac_subject_name']) ) echo esc_attr ( $fhaac_stored_subject_meta 
['fhaac_subject_name'][0] ); ?>"/></div>
```

I have set the `save_post` into a function below:

```
function fhaac_save_subject_meta( $post_id ){
//Checking save status
$is_autosave = wp_is_post_autosave( $post_id );
$is_revision = wp_is_post_revision( $post_id );
$is_valid_nonce = ( isset( $_POST[ 'fhacc_subject_nounce' ] ) && 
wp_verify_nonce( $_POST[ 'fhacc_subject_nounce' ], basename(__FILE__ 
)))?'true' : 'false';

//Exit scripts depending on save status
if ( $is_autosave || $is_revision || !$is_valid_nonce){
    return;
}
if ( isset( $_POST['fhaac_subject_name'])){
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'fhaac_subject_name', 
    sanitize_text_field($_POST['fhaac_subject_name']));
}
```

But either the data isn't saving, or being returned. The issue is, I have this working on a `wp_editor` field. I'm still fairly new to this, so any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

## Try Like below

```
function fhaac_subject_box_callback( $post ){
 wp_nonce_field( basename(__FILE__ ), 'fhacc_subject_nounce');
 $fhaac_stored_subject_meta = get_post_meta( '$post->ID' );
 $fhaac_subject_name = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'my_data_subjectName', true);
?>

<div>Subject name: <input type="text" name="fhaac_subject_name" id="fhaac_
subject_name" value="<?= $fhaac_subject_name; ?>"/></div>
```

Comment: It kind of worked. It output a value and data, but then when trying to save over, it disappears and doesn't save. This is even after I add the 'save_post' hook. Ideas?

Comment: Figured it out! I had `"$post_id"` instead of just `$post_id`. Only got there after looking at your code @omar thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Needed to remove quatation marks on `"$post_id"`:

`$fhaac_stored_subject_meta = get_post_meta( '$post->ID' );`

needed to become

`$fhaac_stored_subject_meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID );`

All sorted now.